# Send game Invitation through google play services on specific user email id

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am using GooglePlaySerivces, Is there any Api to send the game invitation to join or play game to specific user on the basis of user id/email id. I have a list of user, i want to send the app invitation if that user is not installed the game, and game invitation if already using the game.

Comment: did you find any solution to this ?